# vba application.ontime return function value

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code in my programme:

`Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:1"), "sub1"`

which works perfectly to call `sub1` every one second. 
But I want to use `Applicaiton.Ontime` to call a function `func` and return value to a variable.

I have tried many alterations for the above code, none has worked. Any suggestions I can still use `Application.OnTime` to call a function or any other ways to do so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use **OnTime** to schedule a **Sub** call and have the Sub perform the function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gary 's comment made me think about this a little bit. This is the first I've tried, but you *can* call a function with the `Application.OnTime`, even a function that takes arguments.

It may require some tweaking to your code. In this example, I use a module-level variable *instead* of returning a value directly to the function.

```
Dim val

Sub Test()
val = Empty
Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:3"), "'MyFunction ""string"", 395, ThisWorkbook.Name'"

Do While IsEmpty(val)
    DoEvents
Loop

MsgBox val

End Sub

Function MyFunction(arg As String, arg2 As Long, Optional nm As String = vbNullString)

val = arg & arg2 & vbCrLf & nm

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks David, I will try this out. But actually I need to call a `sub1` and `MyFunction` at the same time. How can I call multiple functions using `Application.Onime`?

Comment: Hi David, my problem is more complicated than this, to be more clear, what I want to do is to calculate some values every time the data on a same sheet updates (data updates every 3 seconds), then store the values calculated each time to an array. But it turns out that the approach here gives the same values in this array (computed based on the data last shown on the sheet). I am thinking do I have to create a new sheet for each computation, otherwise I guess the formula still only takes data shown at the moment, rather than mesmerises previous data and computed and stored in an array?

Comment: VBA doesn't support multi-threading, so you can't possibly use `OnTime` to schedule more than a single procedure at any given time.  You can of course schedule multiple procedures, but they will execute sequentially, not concurrently.  Does this not answer your original question of "how to run a function from application.ontime"?

Comment: You're welcome! If you have a more specific question/problem, I would suggest asking it as a new question. There *may* be a way to do what you want but we'll need more detail and example code of what you have already tried so far.  Good luck!!